# How to use haml views with fuelPHP?

Tags: twig, haml, fuelphp

I'm trying using [HAML](http://haml.info) with [fuelPHP 1.8](http://www.fuelphp.com)

**First**

I followed piece of advices from https://github.com/fuel/parser by updating `require` part of `composer.json`

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "composer/installers": "~1.0",
    "fuel/core": "1.8.*",
    "fuel/auth": "1.8.*",
    "fuel/email": "1.8.*",
    "fuel/oil": "1.8.*",
    "fuel/orm": "1.8.*",
    "fuel/parser": "1.8.*",
    "fuelphp/upload": "2.0.6",
    "monolog/monolog": "1.18.*",
    "phpseclib/phpseclib": "2.0.0",
    "michelf/php-markdown": "1.4.0",
    "dwoo/dwoo" : "*",
    "mustache/mustache" : "*",
    "smarty/smarty" : "*",
    "twig/twig" : "*",
    "mthaml/mthaml": "*",
    "pyrocms/lex": "*"
},
```

**Then**

I wrote `my-view.haml` in very simple HAML

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{:charset => "utf-8"}/
    %title My View
    %meta{:content => "width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0", :name => "viewport"}/
    %link{:href => "assets/style.min.css", :rel => "stylesheet"}/
  %body
    %h1 this is my view
```

Then in a controller I pointed to `my-view.haml` with

```
public function action_view()
{
   $view = View::forge('welcome/my-view.haml');
   return Response::forge($view, 200);
}
```

**But**

I obtain following error:

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]:
Method Parser\View_HamlTwig::__toString() must not throw an exception,
caught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Twig_Environment::__construct()
must be an instance of Twig_LoaderInterface,
null given, called in /home/mickro/devel/my-prj/fuel/packages/parser/classes/view/twig.php on line 104
```

**So**

After [investigations](https://github.com/fuel/parser/pull/63) I replaced `my-view.haml` by this [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) version `my-view.haml.twig`

```
{% haml %}
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{:charset => "utf-8"}/
    %title My View
    %meta{:content => "width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0", :name => "viewport"}/
    %link{:href => "assets/style.min.css", :rel => "stylesheet"}/
  %body
    %h1 this is my view
```

when I point to `my-view.haml.twig`

**Twig seems not to know HAML at all**

```
Twig_Error_Syntax [ Error ]:
Unknown "haml" tag.
```

**Where I'm lost**

What is the right way to use HAML with fuelPHP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion on [fuelPHP forum](https://fuelphp.com/forums/discussion/comment/21804#Comment_21804) an [issue](https://github.com/fuel/parser/issues/93) as been opened.

This is a bug due to **haml parser**. It is not compatible with **twig 2**.

I temporary solved my case by removing useless parsers and moving twig to version `1.31.0` as following:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "composer/installers": "~1.0",
    "fuel/core": "1.8.*",
    "fuel/auth": "1.8.*",
    "fuel/email": "1.8.*",
    "fuel/oil": "1.8.*",
    "fuel/orm": "1.8.*",
    "fuel/parser": "1.8.*",
    "fuelphp/upload": "2.0.6",
    "monolog/monolog": "1.18.*",
    "phpseclib/phpseclib": "2.0.0",
    "michelf/php-markdown": "1.4.0",
    "twig/twig" : "1.31.0",
    "mthaml/mthaml": "*"
},
```